# Problem with auxiliary constructors in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor

I stumbled over this question: [In Scala, how would I model a bank account in a stateless, functional manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798193/in-scala-how-would-i-model-a-bank-account-in-a-stateless-functional-manner). The proposed solution looks plausible:

```
// Here is the important part of the answer
class Account(balance: Int) {
    def deposit(amount: Int): Account // the implementation was left out...
}
```

The problem I have with this solution is that the primary constructor is public. So if the user programmer creates a new account he can pass an arbitrary value to it. What if I always want it to be zero? It's a new account anyway, why should its amount be anything else than zero?

As far as I know it is impossible to make a **public class** with a **private primary constructor.** On the other hand it is possible for an **auxiliary constructor** to be **private**, which is exactly what I tried to do.

```
class Account {
  val balance = 0

  private def this(amount: Int) = {
    this()
    balance = amount // won't compile since balance is a val
  }

  def deposit(amount: Int): Account = new Account(balance + amount)
}
```

I know exactly what the problem is, but I have no idea how to fix it, which is kinda embarrassing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Private and protected constructor in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730536/private-and-protected-constructor-in-scala)

Comment: @oluies -- that is *not* a dup.  It's a different question with the same answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primary constructors can in fact be private:

```
case class Account private(balance:Int)

object Account {
  def apply() = new Account(0)
}

println(Account())
//doesn't compile: println(Account(100))
```

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation of Kim's excellent answer, without the companion object:

```
class Account private(balance:Int) {
  def this() = {
    this(0)
  }  
  def deposit(amount: Int): Account = new Account(balance + amount)
}
```

Comment: Thx, Kim has modified it actually. His answer was originally something like: "primary constructors can be private" and one line of code, which showed the syntax (which was enough for me). But thx anyway.